# Equivalent of Python's dir function in PHP

Tags: php, python

Is there any equivalent method of Python's [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) in PHP? It would be really nice if I could see what method(s) are associated with a certain data type or class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Afaik PHP has no equivalent to just `dir`, but you can get such information with functions like `get_class_methods`: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.classobj.php